# Does Rogue One reference A New Hope in the way the Death Star's firing is depicted?

Tags: star-wars, reference, rogue-one

I just saw Rogue One and have a question about a possible reference, if it is one.

The Death Star is used twice in RO, just as in A New Hope (it is destroyed before firing the second time in ANH).

In ANH, they used the same footage for the preparation of the blast. In RO I think that I noticed that they also use the same footage (not the footage from ANH but from RO) twice.

Might this be a reference or is it just my imagination?

Comment: Technically it's a *callback* not an Easter Egg but...potayto/potahto.

Comment: When you say "material", do you mean they used the same shots/footage/film segment?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. Sorry for the wrong use of vocabulary, I'm totally new to movies.stackechange :)

Comment: Wasn't it all CGI? In that case, generating the shot footage would by definition use the same underlying programming, even if it was indeed different shots.

Comment: I don't think that the shots were CGI, they did Tarkin in CGI though. But the "preparation" shots for the Death Star blast were (mostly, I'm not entirely sure about everything) non-CGI imo.

Comment: They do use some of the original footage in the shots of the technicians that do that actual button pressing.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the similarities between the shots of the firing sequence, it is surely a tribute to *A New Hope*.

But the shots are not exactly the same. There are slight differences.

[There's a cool side-by-side video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kvrCjfnS5SM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kvrCjfnS5SM)